# Extending existing project and installing both of them at same time on android mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, zxing

Hi i made an app barcodescanner using ZXing project.actually i added some code in this BarCodeScanner project now its running fine on my wildfire s and on emulator.but when i installed zxing barcode scanner app from android market .and again try to install it then it is not installing on my phone.and same when i installed it on my phone then i am not able to install barcode scanner from android market.please suggest any way or  any modification in manifest file so that i can  install both of them at same time or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't stated what the error message is when you try to install the second time, I am assuming there is a package name conflict.

Are you sure you have used your own package name in the code, including the manifest (and parts that may have the package name hardcoded)?

If not, you must make sure your code uses your own package name, and that the manifest file reflects that.

(Note that it's probably unwise to tamper with the package name in the ZXing code)

Comment: No problem. Make sure to take Sean Owen's advice here, and look at the licence of ZXing before you release anything to the public

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have so extensively copied and pasted our code from http://code.google.com/p/zxing that you didn't bother to change the package name. We find this unethical. I would request that you not publish a simple copy-and-paste version of our work. Write your own app. Use pieces of ours for inspiration if you need to.

Comment: hi i am calling capttureActivity from my activity for scanning the code.i wrote more than 1000 lines of code i am only scanning the barcode in my activity then calling google product api for getting information about product in json then parsing it n list view then i put check boxes in listview so that user can check which information he has to send to other user using sms.when he click on send it button it sends the sms.i am using your code but its looking different and its not a simple copy and paste.i am taking part in thrutu developer competition.http://thrutu.com/developer-contest/

Comment: if still its unethical.please tell me i will leave the development on the app but i am using this library for scanning barcode the remaining code is mine.please replyy fast because only 2 days are remaining and i am planning for publishing it tomorrow morning.

Comment: It is up to your judgment. You do need to make it clear that you used Apache-licensed software from a third party.